# Collision detection on Processing

Tags: processing, collision-detection, game-physics

I have a Space Invaders game I am working on. Very basic and simple. So far I have a shooter that moves (left and right) and shoots. I also have one invader that moves in a pattern. I want the bullets to make the invader disappear.

So my question is how do I get collision detection to work (not colour collision)? If anyone can show me how it´s done then I will be grateful.

Note: I have been called out for putting in too much code in the past so I hope that just the Bullet and Invader class is the right way to do it.

```java
ArrayList <Bullet> bullets;

class Bullet
{
  float x;
  float y;
  float speed;
  Bullet(float tx, float ty)
  {
    x = tx;
    y = ty;
  }
  void display()
  {
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    fill(255);
    ellipse(x,y, 10, 10);
  }
  void move()
  {
    y -= 5;

}
}
void moveAll()
{
  for(Bullet temp : bullets)
  {
    temp.move();
  }
}
void displayAll()
{
  for(Bullet temp : bullets)
  {
    temp.display();
  }
}
```

```java
Cell[][] grid;

float i, j;

boolean b3=false;
boolean b4=true;
boolean b5=false;

int cols = 5;
int rows = 2;
color pixel;

class Cell {
  float cX,cY;   


  Cell(float tempX, float tempY, float tempW, float tempH) {
    cX = tempX;
    cY = tempY;
  } 

  void display2() {
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(cX+30,cY+100,5,5);
    rect(cX+35,cY+95,5,5);
    rect(cX+35,cY+90,5,5);
    rect(cX+40,cY+85,5,5);
    rect(cX+45,cY+80,5,5);
    rect(cX+50,cY+80,5,5);
    rect(cX+55,cY+75,5,5);
    rect(cX+60,cY+75,5,5);
    rect(cX+65,cY+75,5,5);
    rect(cX+70,cY+75,5,5);
    rect(cX+75,cY+80,5,5);
    rect(cX+80,cY+80,5,5);
    rect(cX+85,cY+85,5,5);
    rect(cX+90,cY+90,5,5);
    rect(cX+90,cY+95,5,5);
    rect(cX+95,cY+100,5,5);
    rect(cX+95,cY+105,5,5);
    rect(cX+95,cY+110,5,5);
    rect(cX+95,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+90,cY+120,5,5);
    rect(cX+85,cY+120,5,5);
    rect(cX+80,cY+120,5,5);
    rect(cX+75,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+70,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+70,cY+120,5,5);
    rect(cX+70,cY+125,5,5);
    rect(cX+65,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+60,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+55,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+55,cY+120,5,5);
    rect(cX+55,cY+125,5,5);
    rect(cX+50,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+45,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+45,cY+120,5,5);
    rect(cX+40,cY+120,5,5);
    rect(cX+35,cY+120,5,5);
    rect(cX+30,cY+115,5,5);
    rect(cX+30,cY+110,5,5);
    rect(cX+30,cY+105,5,5);
    rect(cX+40,cY+125,5,5);
    rect(cX+40,cY+130,5,5);
    rect(cX+45,cY+135,5,5);
    rect(cX+50,cY+140,5,5);
    rect(cX+55,cY+140,5,5);
    rect(cX+60,cY+140,5,5);
    rect(cX+65,cY+140,5,5);
    rect(cX+70,cY+140,5,5);
    rect(cX+75,cY+140,5,5);
    rect(cX+80,cY+135,5,5);
    rect(cX+85,cY+130,5,5);
    rect(cX+85,cY+125,5,5);



   if(b4==true) {  //moving right
      b3 = false;
      b5 = false;
      cX += 2;
    }
    else if(b5==true) { //moving left
      b3 = false;
      b4 = false;
      cX -= 2;
    }

   if( (b4 == true && cX >= 780) || (b5 == true && cX <= -1)) 
   {
      b3 = true;  //moving down
      b4 = false;
      b5 = false;
    }

   if( b3 == true) //moving down
   {
       cY += 3;
      if (cY % 10 == 0)  //moving down 10 pixels
      {
        b3=false;
        if ( cX >= 780)  //if it is on the right edge
        {
          b4 = false;
          b5 = true;
        }
         else if ( cX <= -1 ) //if it is on the left edge
        {
          b4 = true;
          b5 = false;
          cY += 3;
        }
      }
  }
  }

  void monster()
  {
          display2();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to handle collision detection, which makes this a pretty broad question. But I'll focus on two approaches that would likely be useful:

**Approach 1: Circle Collision**

If you know the center and size of two objects, you can simply use the `dist()` function to figure out how far apart the two objects are. If that distance is less than their sizes, then the objects are colliding.

Here's a little example:

```java
void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  float circleOneX = width/2;
  float circleOneY = height/2;
  float circleOneRadius = 50;

  float circleTwoX = mouseX;
  float circleTwoY = mouseY;
  float circleTwoRadius = 100;

  if (dist(circleOneX, circleOneY, circleTwoX, circleTwoY) < circleOneRadius + circleTwoRadius) {
    //colliding!
    fill(255, 0, 0);
  } else {
    //not colliding!
    fill(0, 255, 0);
  }

  ellipse(circleOneX, circleOneY, circleOneRadius, circleOneRadius);
  ellipse(circleTwoX, circleTwoY, circleTwoRadius, circleTwoRadius);
}
```

**Approach 2: Rectangle Collision**

Alternatively, you can define a bounding box around your objects. Then you just need a series of if statements to check whether those boxes overlap at all. If so, then the objects are colliding.

Here's a little example:

```java
void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  float rectOneX = width/2;
  float rectOneY = height/2;
  float rectOneWidth = 50;
  float rectOneHeight = 50;

  float rectTwoX = mouseX;
  float rectTwoY = mouseY;
  float rectTwoWidth = 100;
  float rectTwoHeight = 100;

  if (rectOneX < rectTwoX + rectTwoWidth &&
    rectOneX + rectOneWidth > rectTwoX &&
    rectOneY < rectTwoY + rectTwoHeight &&
    rectOneHeight + rectOneY > rectTwoY) {
    //colliding!
    fill(255, 0, 0);
  } else {
    //not colliding!
    fill(0, 255, 0);
  }

  rect(rectOneX, rectOneY, rectOneWidth, rectOneHeight);
  rect(rectTwoX, rectTwoY, rectTwoWidth, rectTwoHeight);
}
```

Both of these approaches are introduced in [the button example](https://www.processing.org/examples/button.html) that comes with Processing.

Comment: Thank you, Kevin, The first example, does it only apply to just circles or any object?

Comment: @FredTheHomie Imagine drawing a circle around your objects. You can then just do collision between the circles. That won't work for every case, but it'll work for many simple cases. Think about it this way: the circles are imaginary. You don't actually have to draw them. You're just using them to make collision between objects easier. Same with the rectangular bounding box.

Comment: I understand, this is making sense. So, say my invader, I have an imagery circle around it? So how do I put this "circle" around it?

Comment: @FredTheHomie You have to figure out the center of your invader, and you have to figure out its size. That's your circle. Try drawing a few examples on paper.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much. You helped me straight away. I appreciate you, brother.